# Find a left-inverse for the function $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ given by $f(n)=2n+1$.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, inverse-function

Find a left-inverse for the function $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ given by $f(n)=2n+1$.

Verify that your answer is correct. Does f have a right-inverse? Explain.

---

Hi all, I need to asses whether this function is left and/or right invertible, and then prove it using proper proof language. I'm trying to follow the way my professor taught me, but I'm not really sure I understand what I'm doing.

This is what I have:

*Theorem.* $f$ is left-invertible.

*Proof.*

$f$ is left-invertible if there is some function $g:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ such that $g \circ f = id_{\Bbb Z}$. Consider $g(n)=\frac{n-1}{2}$. Then, $g \circ f(n) =\frac{2n+1-1}{2}=n=id_{\Bbb Z}$. Therefore, $f$ is left-invertible.

Does that make any sense so far? Honestly, it doesn't  make any sense to me. The other problem is that using a similar strategy, I find that $f$ is also right-invertible. However, I know that not to be true, because $f(1)=3$ and $f(2)=5$, and thus there is no $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $f(n)=4$ (aka, the function only spits out odd numbers if we restrict the domain to integer inputs). Therefore, it is not survective. If anyone can help me understand, perhaps from the beginning, how to properly do this problem and write it out, that would be amazing.

Cheers

Comment: What function do you see as a right inverse to $f$?

Comment: The same function, which is obviously absurd. This is what I'd written for that part before I realized I must be very confused:

$f$ is right-invertible if there is some function $h: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ such that $f \circ h=id_{\Bbb Z}$. Consider $h(n)=\frac{n-1}{2}$. Then, $f \circ h(n)=2(\frac{n-1}{2})+1=n=id_{\Bbb Z}n$. Therefore, f is right-invertible. 

What am I thinking??

Comment: Your construction of a left inverse is somewhat flawed, in that the function you write down is not a function from $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$.  It only takes integer values if $n$ is odd, which is good enough since the image of $f$ consists of odd integers.

Comment: It's easy to get confused, no worries there.  The problem with your  $h$, of course, is that it isn't integer valued when $n$ is even.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. How do I prove, then, that there does not exist an $h$ for which $f \circ h = id_{\Bbb Z}$?

Comment: You already have!  Suppose $h$ existed.  Then $f(h(4))=4$, by definition of right inverse.  But $f(n)$ is odd for all $n$, a contradiction!

Comment: Worth noting:  your function $f$ makes sense on all of $\mathbb Q$ and in that context your function $h$ is a perfectly good inverse.

Comment: Oh! Perfect. That makes sense. Is my notation and logic sufficient? I am not used to using the identity function notation. I'm more used to just thinking left and right invertible as simply trying to find inverse functions that work for certain compositions.

Comment: I'm not happy with the logic, quite.  Saying $f(1)=3, f(3)=5$ doesn't prove that $f(n)=4$ is impossible.  I'd get that result by arguing that for all $n$, $f(n)$ is odd.

Comment: Also, you say that my $g$ function is flawed because it only takes integer values if $n$ is odd. 

However, don't I stipulate in the proof that $g$ is to have domain and range $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$? As such, isn't it assumed that whatever function I propose will be restricted to that domain?

Comment: Yes, to perfect your argument you need to redefine $g$ so that it takes integers to integers.  The answer provided by @Bernard does that in a very natural way.  You could also just define $g(n)=\frac {n-1}2$ when $n$ is odd and set  $g(n)=0$ when $n$ is even (or whatever you like really). It doesn't really matter what $g$ does to even numbers!

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! For some reason, it is more straightforward for me to prove injectivity and surjectivity using the symbolic definitions of those properties, and then from there I can tell what is left/right invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula for $g(n)$ doesn't ensure $g(n)\in\mathbf Z$. To make it work, you should take
$$g(n)=\biggl\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\biggr\rfloor.$$

If $f$ had a right inverse, it would be surjective, which isn't the case.

Note that a function with a left inverse is injective, which is indeed the case.

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with that notation (the bracket-looking things surrounding the expression). What does that mean?

Comment: By the way, I could have proved this by proving that it was injective and not surjective (since I know how to do that). But I'm required to prove this using the composition concepts specifically.

Comment: @akot717 The brackets indicate the floor function - it means to round the input down to the next integer. (e.g. $\lfloor 2+\frac{1}2\rfloor = 2$ and $\lfloor \frac{-1}2\rfloor= -1$ and $\lfloor 5\rfloor = 5$)

Comment: I see. 

But why do I need to write $g(n)$ as a floor function if I have already indicated that my function has domain $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: That's because $\frac{n-1}2$ is not an integer if $n$ is even